# How to Set config params in Slick-HikariCP

Tags: mysql, scala, hikaricp, slick-3.0

I am using Slick and Mysql. Getting the Error:

```
Failed to validate connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@58e7cfcd (No operations allowed after connection closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value."
```

I understand the issue but don't know how to set [maxLifetime](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#gear-configuration-knobs-baby)  in slick on config. Here is my config:

```
mysqldb {
    driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306"
    user = root
    password = root
    connectionTimeout = 10000
    queueSize = 50000
    minConnections = 20
    maxConnections = 40
    numThreads = 40
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set under db config:

```
mysqldb {
    driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306"
    user = root
    password = root
    connectionTimeout = 10000
    queueSize = 50000
    minConnections = 20
    maxConnections = 40
    numThreads = 40
    idleTimeout = 85000 // should be less than maxLifetime
    maxLifetime = 90000 //time is in millsecods and should be less than database wait_timeout
}
```